# autocomplete in jquery ajax and php5

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete

> index.php

```
  <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control autosuggest" placeholder="Search for">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
             <div class="dropdown">
                    <ul class="result">

                    </ul>
                </div>
```

> jquery/ajax file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".autosuggest").keyup(function() {
    var search_term  = $(this).attr('search');
    var dataString = 'search_term='+ search_term;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url : 'search.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

});
```

> search.php file

```
<?php
include 'includes/db.php';

if(isset($_POST['search_term']) && !empty($_POST['search_term'])) {
    $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search_term']);
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name LIKE $search_term%";
    $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql)) {
        echo "<li>$rows[name]</li>";
    }
  }
?>
```

> I am just making a simple autocomple suggestion in php mysql and ajax, my php version is 5 and jquery version is 2,i want to populate my mysql data in autosuggest container,First i am trying to alert the data on page with the help of javascript alert function but thrie is some error,can anyone please review my code

**Thank you**

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Error is something like mysqli_fetch_assoc takes two parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes arround search variable

```
 $sql = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name LIKE '$search_term%' ";
```